# What does a developer need on the front end to ensure a successful project?

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails

I have an idea for a business that requires a well designed web application. I'm not a rocket surgeon, but I'm smart enough to know that you get what you pay for and am willing to pay for talent. However, I want the development process to go as smoothly as possible and would like to know how to make that happen.

So, what information do developers need (or want) initially from the owner to avoid having to make assumptions about business (or other) requirements? Do I need to create state transition diagrams or write use cases?

Essentially, how do I take the concept in my head and package it in a way that allows the developer to do what they do best? (assuming that is creating good software. haha)

Any advice is appreciated.

Shawn

Comment: Is a Rocket Surgeon someone who performs surgery on a rocket or a rocket that performs surgery on someone? :)  Rocket surgeon, rocket scientist, brain surgeon... does the pope sh1t in the woods?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to reword your question, as it is too general to get a good answer, so some vague details would be helpful.

But, the better vision you have of what you want the smoother it will be.

I find UML diagrams too confining, when you aren't going to be doing the work, as you may not come up with the best design.

So, if you start with designing out what each page should look like, as you envision it, then you can write up use cases, which are short scenarios.

So, you may write up:

A user needs to be able to log in using OpenID.

This will tell the developer one function that you want, and who you expect to do that action.

But, don't put in technologies, as you may think that a SOAP service is your best bet, but upon talking about it you may find that there is a better solution.

Use cases are good points to show what you are envisioning, and give text to your page designs.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to the developers. Explain what you want and *why* you want it. Together you make the flow charts and whatnot. Writing requirements is part of the design process, and it's a good idea to have the developers onboard as soon as possible. Start simple and small, then grow and expand while iterating.

Answer (score 0):

In talking over web services before, I have found the best starting point is drawing on a sheet of paper what you think the site will look like, and add in a few arrows from things you want clickable to the pages that should result. Keep it simple, nothing too fancy, and hopefully you and the developer can come to an understanding of what you want pretty quickly.

Use cases might be best for checking off all the points later in the project about how complete your site is; I haven't really found it to be a helpful starting point, but I'm sure others disagree. (They just seem too *tedius* to *read* when actually writing code.)

Same with state transition diagrams; they are too tedious and I think most developers will assume you made mistakes in them anyway. :) Everyone else does... Unless your project hinges *very* tightly on the correctness of a state machine, I wouldn't really bother.

Answer (score 0):

This [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1884777597) contains some good advice on what constitutes a good statement of requirements from a programmers point of view. It also has the useful guideline of not trying to set the form of your requirements too early, and a substantial piece on describing the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I like UI mockups based on actual program/site flows e.g registering a customer or placing order. Diagrams/pictures of GUIs with structured, consistent data examples are unambiguous.

I agree that UML and use cases are only really useful if everyone speaks UML and the projects are of sufficient complexity (few are).

You may want to read up on Agile/Scrum techniques. These are becoming a sort of standard and when properly managed can save weeks of development time.

Answer (score 0):

I find that words don't do a good job of communicating how a system is supposed to work. Wireframes, white-board drawings/transition diagrams, and low-fidelity prototypes are great ways to communicate a concrete idea. One example of a low-fidelity prototype is a "clickable" paper prototype that allows a user to touch "buttons" on paper to go from one drawing to another. It costs very little time (cheaper), but goes a long way to communicate an idea between two parties.

Stay away from formal documentation, UML diagrams, or class (technical documentation) diagrams that don't speak to you. This is what large, risk-averse companies move toward to be more "mature". These are also byproducts of an idea that is hashed out, and it sounds like you're in the hashing out stage.